# vertically div inside heading on the same line

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, html-heading, heading

After I kept trying I made some tweaks that would allow me to have the div on the same line with h3, but it's not centered. I simply want to have the div on the same line, next to the h3, with vertically centered h3 text (or the div, it doesn't matter as long as text appears .

I guess that `position: absolute;` is a problem, but if I remove it, the circle around the number won't be a circle anymore (and I need to keep it a circle)
 As it is now, the circle will be positioned on the same line, but it vertically aligns top, if the heading text has enough space on the page (one line)
[image]

or bottom, if the heading text goes on two lines (due to being too long)
[image]

And also add 10px between the circle and the text, horizontally.

I use this html:

```
 <h3> <div class="numberCircle">
<div class="content">24</div> </div>Smallest Personal Computer - Micro Mote </h3>
```

and this css:

```
 .numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 50px;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    position: relative;

}
.numberCircle:before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  margin-top:100%;
}
.numberCircle .content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

for h3:

```
 h3 {
  line-height: 1.17391em;
  color: #242d36;
  font-family: "PT Serif", Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 27px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9ebz77p1/ works ok on chrome.

Comment: Do you have the html you specified inside another element? If so, does that element have a width and height? (Also works for me in most browsers as-is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve it changing a bit your HTML and moving the flexbox to the wrapper.

```css
 .numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 50px;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    position: relative;

}
.numberCircle:before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  margin-top:100%;
}
.numberCircle .content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
h3 {
  line-height: 1.17391em;
  color: #242d36;
  font-family: "PT Serif", Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 27px 0;
  vertical-align:middle; 
}
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="numberCircle">
    <div class="content">24</div>
  </div>
  <h3>Smallest Personal Computer - Micro Mote </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make this easy for yourself by rather using a table.

Check this out:

CSS:

```
.MyTable {
    width: 300px;
}

.MyTable tr td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle {
    background: red;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.text {
    background: green;
    font-family: "PT Serif", Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="MyTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="circle">
                24
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text">
            Smallest Personal Computer - Micro Mote
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With this, you don't have to worry about the line-heigt, and all those "itty gritty" stuff. You will be able to change your font-size and still have your text centered perfectly.